# Opening Realm files of format version 11 is not supported by this version of Realm in Realm Studio

Tags: realm, react-native, realm-studio

I am working with React-Native. In this I am referring [this](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/) documentation to use Realm Database in React-Native. I can create react-native database but unable to open it in Realm-Studio - V3.11.0. When I am opening saved Realm file in studio it shows me below message.
My realm version in node is 6.0.0

[image]

What I want to open and see data inside it. If there is any other solutions do let me know.
I referred other links but this problem I found different so creating new Question for it.

Comment: It looks like you're using the MongoDB Realm with file format 10. You will need to use Realm Studio 10 to open that. Try a newer (beta) version [Realm Studio](https://github.com/realm/realm-studio/releases). Keep in mind that if you open an older file with the newer Realm Studio it will update it so ensure you have a backup.

Comment: What is the solution?  I am facing the same problem.

Comment: what is the solution? I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Installation **MongoDB Realm Studio** from https://docs.realm.io/sync/realm-studio solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install MongoDB Realm Studio.

New Realm Studio is available 5.0.1
https://studio-releases.realm.io/v5.0.1/download/mac-dmg

Upgrade and that's all.