# Opening Realm files of format version 22 is not supported by this version of Realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm

When I try to open realm files with Real Studio Application, I get this error "Opening Realm files of format version 22 is not supported by this version of Realm".

I read posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63955783/opening-realm-files-of-format-version-11-is-not-supported-by-this-version-of-rea) on Stack Overflow which seems to ask a similar question. But the answers on there did not solve my question. I uninstalled my Realm Studio Application and reinstalled Realm Studio Application with the newest version (10.1.2 at this time of writing) and deleted my Realm files and created new ones with the newest SDK but I still get this error:[image]

Their official documentation says

> If you open an older version of a realm file in a newer Realm Studio
> version, you may see a prompt to upgrade your realm file. Once
> upgraded, you cannot revert to the older file version. You may also
> need to upgrade your SDK to a version that supports the newer file
> format.

How can you see your files again?

#### [**Solved**]

Realm released Realm Studio version 11 which supports opening files with format 22. If you have realm files with format version 22 and haven't upgraded your Realm Studio, upgrade your Realm Studio from Realm's official website and you won't see an error message like above.

Comment: "When I try to open realm files with Real Studio Application"  Que!?  Where do you get it?

Comment: You already posted a similar topic a few day ago, didn't you?  The error message sounds clear to me.

Comment: @ElTomato This is the first time I am asking this question. and I don't see how your comment is related in any way to this question..

Comment: So apparently, format version 22 is the latest file version for realm files and my Realm Studio (although the latest release at this time of writing 10.1.2) does not support viewing realm files of format version 22 yet. You'd have to wait until they release Realm Studio 11 which will support viewing realm files of format version 22...

Comment: I believe the question is answered by the [Realm Release Notes](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/releases) which states *Realm Studio: 11.0.0 or later. Note that this version of Realm Studio has not
yet been released at the time of this release*. However, there is a beta version available which can be found in the [Realm Studio Releases](https://github.com/realm/realm-studio/releases). Always a good idea to check documentation before posting questions.

Comment: The new Realm/MondoDB release is out. Solved my format 22 issue. https://github.com/realm/realm-studio

Answer (score 2):

I had realm studio 10.x.x and it didn't get update for realm studio 11.x.x. I have manually uninstalled realm studio 10.x.x and installed [latest](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm-legacy/products/realm-studio.html) version(11.x.x.)and got the fix.

Comment: Right - and surprisingly "Check for updates" also returned "this is the latest version" for 10.x.y even though 11.1.2 was available - had to manually uninstall it on mac and reinstall the latest version.

Comment: Thanks! The same deception about the lack of a new version. I had 10.x.x, and the site already had 14.x.x :(